# Is the value of the scalar components of the Higgs field known?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, vacuum, higgs, symmetry-breaking

As I understand the relevant popular sources ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism#Abelian_Higgs_mechanism)), since the end of the [Electroweak epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_epoch), the Higgs field became fixed in the whole known Universe. Thus, we are somewhere on the deep blue part (which is really a 4-sphere) of the Mexican hat potential, and this is a constant value of the Higgs field everywhere. Of course $\rm{|\phi|=246GeV}$.

[image]

This should mean that we have 2 complex (or 4 scalar) universal physical constants, from which we know that their square sum is 246GeV.

But, is the induvidual values of these contants known? What is the value of the 4 real (2 complex) components of the Higgs field now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "we" are the vacuum, then, yes, we are on the blue minimum of a 4D Goldstone sombrero. The blue minimum is not a circle as in the 2D picture,
but, instead, a three sphere, a hypersphere of the three goldstons eaten up in the Higgs mechanism.

The expectation values are, by convention,
$$
\langle \phi^0 \rangle = v = \langle \Re \phi^0 \rangle \qquad  \langle \Im \phi^0 \rangle = 0= \langle  \phi^+ \rangle.
$$
These are at the minimum of the sombrero. Oscillations around the minimum are the *h* field and the would-be-goldstons, which have been rearranged into pieces of the gauge fields.

Comment: Thus, being on another (minimal energy) point, we would have exactly the same rest masses?

Comment: Yes, any point (vacuum choice) on said O(4)/O(3) hypersphere will result in an identical theory, provided we *redefine* our manifold coordinates to describe the same entities.